# down menu will only give error

Tags: php, html, mysqli

this is how I have dropdown menu and if I take one of them as I have down menu, then comes the only forward with errors all the time.

it only appears with errors and provides only error so I can not move on.

**PHP**

```
if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT navn FROM fms_styrkemaal WHERE navn != ?')) { 
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $navn);
    $navn = $_POST["styrkemaal"];
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($navn);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $error = 1;
    }
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklæringen: ' . $this->mysqli->error;
}
if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT navn FROM fms_kon WHERE navn != ?')) { 
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $navn);
    $navn = $_POST["kon"];
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($navn);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $error = 1;
    }
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklæringen: ' . $this->mysqli->error;
}
if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT uger FROM fms_uger WHERE uger != ?')) { 
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $uger);
    $uger = $_POST["uger"];
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($uger);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $error = 1;
    }
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklæringen: ' . $this->mysqli->error;
}
```

**html / php**

```
<select name="kon">
<?php
if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT id, navn FROM fms_kon')) { 
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $navn);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $navn;?>"><?php echo $navn;?></option>
    <?php
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
?>
</select>
<select name="uger">
<?php
if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT id, uger FROM fms_uger')) { 
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $uger);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $uger;?>"><?php echo $uger;?></option>
    <?php
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
?>
</select>
<select name="styrkemaal">
<?php
if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT id, navn FROM fms_styrkemaal')) { 
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $navn);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $navn;?>"><?php echo $navn;?></option>
    <?php
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: @edvinas.me I for my own mistake coming out of the `$error = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) Your function is vulnerable to SQL injection, you should always escape your data before including it in a SQL query.

2.) You are binding to a variable that hasn't got a value.

3.) You are doing a string comparison like value comparison.

Try this:

```
...
// This is really bad practice...
$navn = $_POST["styrkemaal"];
...
try {
   if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT navn FROM fms_styrkemaal WHERE navn like ':v_navn'")) { 
        $stmt->bind_param(':v_navn', $navn, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
          print_r($row);
        }
        $stmt->close();
    } else {
        echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklæringen: ' . $this->mysqli->error;
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```